# Which one is better, defining two tables, or having a boolean flag to determine the type of a user

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm designing the database for one of my projects, and we have two types of users, a normal user (default), and a bushiness user, they have identical attributes but differ on abilities, for instance.

A business user can post a job, whereas the normal user can only apply to jobs and nothing more, which one is the preferred way of doing so.

**Method 1**

Define two different tables: will cost storage space since both users have identical attributes

or

**Method 2**

Having a boolean flag to determine the type of user ex `is_business_account` attribute, which might bloat the code with if, else conditions.

This can be solved with roles but do i need to define such table for roles or ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: For further changes, creating a new table would be easier instead of spending some time on the code. This is what I normally do.

Comment: Also, be careful with spelling when defining columns, ie `is_business_account` not `is_buissness_account`. Often it's not worth fixing the spelling of a column name - the change cost to appiications is too high. I once worked with a survey system that had a column named `anwser`. It stayed like that because the app worked and the total risk of change wasn't worth the minor (or in my case major) annoyance.

Comment: Do you also have some queries that work the same for both types?

Comment: It depends on your case.  Most of the time, a single table with a column for type of user is going to cause less trouble than two tables.

Comment: @RickJames no, some queries are different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating entities, you don't want to have multiple entities that are really the same. In your case, you have Users as an entity (table) and one of the attributes is whether or not they are a business user. As part of your program, when the user signs in, you check the user against 1 table to log in and which set of functions to display.

Comment: Yes! Prefer more rows over more tables. Prefer more columns over more rows.

Comment: yes, my plan for implementing this is by using roles, the simplest and most convenient way i found